# How to troubleshoot hash comparisons

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to create an array of hashes of all the people I can direct-message on twitter. The correct array would look like `[{id:12345,name:"john", profile_pic:"some_url"},{id:67890,name:"jim", profile_pic:"some_url"}]`

I'm fetching all_followers and all_friends and comparing the contents of the two.  each object returned is an array of hashes. I'm iterating through one array and grabbing the ID, then iterating through the second array and checking to see if the hash contains that id value. If so, I grab a few details from the original hash and send it into a smaller hash that is ultimately destined for my browser.

The code to do this is:

```
  def get_direct_message_list(friend_list,follower_list)
    names_and_pics = []
    friend_list.each do |base|
      follower_list.each do |compare|
        if compare.has_value?(base["id"])
          block_hash = {}
          block_hash["id"] = base["id"]
          block_hash["name"] = base["name"]
          block_hash["profile_background_image_url"] = base["profile_background_image_url"]
          names_and_pics << block_hash
        end

      end
    end
    names_and_pics
  end
```

It essentially is working. My test suite looks as follows, and the tests are passing.

```
  context "get_direct_message_list" do

    it "should take friends and followers and return name, pic and twitter_id in one list"  do
      followers = [{"id"=>1, "name" => "john", "profile_background_image_url" => "http://somewhere.com"}, {"id"=>2},{"id"=>3, "name" => "mike", "profile_background_image_url" => "http://somewhere.com"}]
      friends = [{"id"=>1, "name" => "john", "profile_background_image_url" => "http://somewhere.com"},{"id"=>5, "name"=>"someoneelse", "profile_background_image_url"=> "http://somewhere"},{"id"=>4},{"id"=>3, "name" => "mike", "profile_background_image_url" => "http://somewhere.com"}]

      get_direct_message_list(friends, followers).should == [{"id"=>1, "name" => "john", "profile_background_image_url" => "http://somewhere.com"},{"id"=>3, "name" => "mike", "profile_background_image_url" => "http://somewhere.com"}]
    end
  end
```

My problem is that the array being returned has some odd duplication, i.e. specifically the Twitter IDs of 12 and 13, biz stone and jack dorsey, both people who do not follow me. They are each being replicated in the final array 3 and 7 times.  I'm not really sure what to be looking at to trouble shoot this.  My first thought was that something like `hashx.has_value?(13)` was returning true when a twitter id of `134567' was being encountered but further experimentation with`.has_value?` indicates that the matching is exact. What can I be looking at?

Comment: It would be hard to say what the cause is without seeing the data you're comparing. I'd start by creating another test case from data that's causing you trouble.

Comment: agreed, the issue is that the data is coming in as a callback from twitter, i'm not entirely sure how to setup tests with actual data, that or I should capture an example return object and run the tests on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `compare.has_value?(base["id"])` will return `true` if *anything* within `compare.values` equals `base["id"]`.

for example:

```
{:id => 12345, :foo => 2}.has_value?(2)
# => true
```

This could be giving you false positives. It's hard to tell if this is the root cause of your problem, but you probably want be more explicit than `compare.has_value?(base["id"])`.

How about something more like `compare["id"] == base["id"]`?

Comment: yes, i was talking about it with a senior rubyist who pays me, he had the same thoughts and since the hash i was searching had so much text, i'm pretty certain this was the problem.  thanks.  we also basically decided the nested loops wasn't optimal and am working it into something else.